Create point along a line from multiple records in PostgreSQL
I have a dataset of motor vehicle crashes in PostgreSQL, and some of them are missing latitude & longitude coordinates, but I have the location based on the milepost of the roadway the crash occurred on. I'm looking for the best way to create points from this. The crashes are in PostgreSQL with geometry points made with PostGIS. I've also added the local roadways to the PostgreSQL database (mercer_roadways). I've been trying (unsuccessfully) to use the ST_LineInterpolatePoint in PostGIS to create the points using the 'SRI' field (which is the key between the crashes and the roadways) and creating a percentage by dividing the milepost location by the length of the roadway.
Here is a sample of the data from the mercer_roadways table:



sri
road_geom
mp_start
mp_end
measured_length




00000129__
MULTILINESTRINGM
0
2.41000008583069
2.41000008583069


00000195__
MULTILINESTRINGM
0
34.1699981689453
34.1699981689453


00000195__
MULTILINESTRINGM
0
34.1699981689453
34.1699981689453


11031471__
MULTILINESTRINGM
0
1.77999997138977
1.77999997138977


11141018__
MULTILINESTRINGM
0
1.75
1.75


11142241__
MULTILINESTRINGM
0
1.57000005245209
1.57000005245209


00000295__
MULTILINESTRINGM
0
76.5599975585938
76.5599975585938



And a sample of the crashes_geocode table:



crash_id
sri
milepost




2021111121006273
00000129__
2.14


20171106C060-2017-01055A
00000295__
71.76


20181102C060-2018-01416A
00000295__
74.40


2018111118010125
11031471__
.74


20181107C060-2018-00122A
00000295__
69.06


20181107C060-2018-01142A
00000295__
69.20


20211103C060-2021-00258A
00000195__
5.40


20211103C060-2021-00537A
00000195__
4.80


20201106C060-2020-00263A
00000295__
72.00


2020111420-08318
11142239__
.52



And here is the code I've been trying to get to work (with the help of ChatGPT):
WITH line_segments AS (
    SELECT SRI, shape, MP_START, MP_END, measured_length
    FROM Mercer_Roadways
),
interpolated_points AS (
    SELECT 
        c.crash_id,
        -- Calculate the interpolated point along the road geometry
         ST_LineInterpolatePoint(
            l.shape,
            (CAST(c.milepost AS numeric) - l.MP_START) / measured_length
        ) AS crash_point
    FROM crashes_geocode c
    JOIN line_segments l
    ON c.SRI = l.SRI
    -- Ensure milepost falls within the segment's range
    WHERE CAST(c.milepost AS numeric) BETWEEN l.MP_START AND l.MP_END
)
UPDATE crashes_geocode
SET crash_point = ip.crash_point
FROM interpolated_points ip
-- Ensure the correct crash records are updated
WHERE crashes_geocode.crash_id = ip.crash_id;

I've tried both ST_LineInterpolatePoint and ST_3DLineInterpolatePoint but they both give the same error "ERROR: line_interpolate_point: 1st arg isn't a line"
I was looking at this ArcGIS tool Generate Points Along Lines but my Python isn't great and I'm not sure how I would make it iterate through all the records in the table. I'm sure it can be done but wanted to make sure there wasn't a simple fix to the path I already started on before scraping it and starting over with a different tool.
Also, I'm running Windows 11 Home, PostgreSQL 16.1, PostGIS v3.4 and ArcGIS Pro 3.3.1

I was able to run the code below by filtering out any geometry that wouldn't convert to a line string. If anyone had a better solution though, I'd love to hear it.
 WITH line_segments AS (
    SELECT r.SRI, 
           ST_LineMerge(ST_Force2D(shape)) AS road_geom, 
           MP_START, 
           MP_END, 
           measured_length
    FROM Mercer_Roadways r
    JOIN crashes_geocode c ON r.sri = c.sri
    WHERE GeometryType(shape) IN ('LINESTRING', 'MULTILINESTRING', 'MULTILINESTRINGM')
),
filtered_segments AS (
    SELECT *,
           CASE 
               WHEN GeometryType(road_geom) = 'LINESTRING' THEN road_geom
               ELSE NULL 
           END AS filtered_road_geom
    FROM line_segments
)
, interpolated_points AS (
    SELECT
        c.sri,
        ST_LineInterpolatePoint(
            l.filtered_road_geom,
            (CAST(c.milepost AS numeric) - l.MP_START) / measured_length
        ) AS crash_geom
    FROM crashes_geocode c
    JOIN filtered_segments l
    ON c.SRI = l.SRI
    WHERE CAST(c.milepost AS numeric) BETWEEN l.MP_START AND l.MP_END
)
UPDATE crashes_geocode
SET crash_point = ip.crash_geom
FROM interpolated_points ip
WHERE crashes_geocode.SRI = ip.sri;

